# "Inconsistent number of matrix lines compared to the number of labels" runtime exception error when importing large CSV file into Gephi

Tags: csv, adjacency-matrix, gephi

The full error is "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Inconsistent number of matrix lines compared to the number of labels."

I am trying to pull an adjacency matrix stored in a CSV file into Gephi so that I can use its modularity optimization tool and make a really slick chart of my data. I compiled the data in Excel (yes, it took forever) and saved it as CSV, and then I opened the file in Notepad and used Ctrl + H to replace all commas with semicolons (and saved it as a CSV file again). My dataset is 5,654 x 5,654 cells, not counting the labels. It is an r-neighborhood graph with r = .6299 (80th percentile and above).

I searched Google and StackOverflow and I only found one solution for my error message: to remove all the spaces in the file. I used Ctrl + H again to remove all spaces, but I received the same error message when I tried to upload the "spaceless" CSV file. Just to double-check that saving it as CSV didn't cause an issue, I checked the CSV by opening it up in Excel. The file opened correctly, but I do not have much experience with CSV files so I do not know if anything was off. It seemed as though all the records were separated by semicolons instead of commas and I did not see any spaces.

Is it the size of my file? I am currently struggling through learning some Python and R, and I would be open to creating this adjacency matrix CSV file in either of those environments and then feeding it to Gephi. I just need a dependable solution that works without bogging my computer down in Excel all afternoon and allows me to be the "slick graph superhero" of my office.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your problem but there is also the [Excel/CSV import spigot](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/excel-csv-converter-to-network/) to whatever it might be useful. Otherwise you could perhaps try to import the network with NodeXL and then save it in GraphML format which can then be opened by Gephi

Answer (score 0):

Good tip from http://social-dynamics.org/gephi-faq/

> A. One thing to try is removing any extra spaces from your csv file.
>   Sometimes these trip up the import. Open the csv file using a simple
>   text editor like NotePad or TextEdit, and then use find/replace to
>   remove any spaces. Save the adjacency matrix and then try importing it
>   again.

Removing spaces helped me to fix the issue.